# Adding Certificate to Local Machine Store

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509, mmc

I've created a self signed certificate and I'm trying to place it in the Root, and Personal stores of the local machine through code.Previously the following code was working:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(PathToCert, Password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
            if (cert != null)
            {
                var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
                if (!store.Certificates.Contains(cert))
                {
                    store.Add(cert);
                }
                store.Close();
                var store1 = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                store1.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
                if (!store1.Certificates.Contains(cert))
                {
                    store1.Add(cert);

                }
                store1.Close();
    }
```

When I try to add the certificate to the stores (even when running as admin) it will not put them into the Local Machine Stores, it puts the certificate in my  **CURRENT USER** store.

How do I make it put the certificate in the **LOCAL MACHINE**?

Comment: If you debug it, and step in to it, does the call to `store.Add` get made, or does it think the store already has the certificate? `Contains` works by comparing the Issuer and Serial. If there is another cert with the same serial and issuer, your Add won't be called.

Comment: You may also want to consider `ReadWrite` instead of `MaxAllowed`. MaxAllowed basically means, if "I can open it as write, then open it with write. If I can't, then open it as read only" but your code always assumes it has write.

Comment: @vcsjones- In debug mode, it opens the store, doesn't see the cert in the store as it should, then goes to add it. However in debug mode, I get access denied when it tries to add it. When I create the exe I dont get the access denied but it does not put the cert in the LOCAL MACHINE store only my CURRENT USER store